# Theming Inside Blocks Drupal 8

Tags: block, content-type, theming, drupal-8, regions

So My issue is this:

I don't know the process to theme inside regions in Drupal 8. I have the knowledge to theme regions by putting {{ page.XXX }} in the twig file (with regions declaration in the YML file) .But for example I have the "Content" region containing 2 blocks: Page Title and Main Page Content. How can I do to theme only the Page Title or the Main Page Content block in the twig file. Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can override the theme by  any one of the below pattern

```
Pattern: block--[module|-delta]].html.twig
Base template: block.html.twig (base location: core/modules/block/templates/block.html.twig)

block--module--delta.html.twig
block--module.html.twig
block.html.twig
```